# How to specifically rewrite/redirect a URL with HTTPS but no subdomain to have WWW. in it through IIS

Tags: windows-10, regex, iis, c#, url-rewriting

SmarterASP is a hosting website that offers free SSL through Cloudflare if you don't want to spend $200 for two years of service on them. The problem is, they don't include all subdomains, only the "www" one. So if you have no subdomains on your site but prefer the convenience of linking like "https://example.com", then your site will not work.

To be clear, every other form of site linking works; "http://example.com," "http://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com" all work. But for the specific case of "https://example.com" it does not.

My question is, using the URL Rewrite module in IIS, is there a way rewrite or redirect a URL that starts with "https://example.com" to "https://www.example.com"? I'm not very good at regex and

Here's the best of what I tried, which I really thought would work:

```
<rule name="rewriteHTTPSnoSUB">
    <match url="www.+" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

In my mind I see this as "if the URL doesn't contain "www.", redirect it to have "www." in it, but it doesn't work because it somehow gets caught in a redirect loop. If I set it to "rewrite" it gives a 404.

I'm not very good at regex though, and I'd like to know if there is a way before I drop $200 on custom SSL from their site, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will you be hosting this `example.com` directly on your own IIS system, with your own certificate, or will you be uploading this configuration to the same SmarterASP?

Comment: @grawity I'm using an identical configuration on my home server (for testing) and SmarterASP (for release). I use Cloudflare SSL on my home server, but I can make a CNAME specifically for empty subdomains. SmarterASP restricts this, so I'm trying to come up with a workaround.

Comment: According to their website, they offer SNI and Lets Encrypt certificates. You should be able to provision these directly via them https://www.smarterasp.net/windows_hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @harrymc suggested, I tried complaining to support, but they said there was no option other than the $200 SSL purchase. Tough luck.

I never found a true answer for the actual question, but I actually was able to workaround it by, instead of using SASP's integrated Cloudflare SSL, using a separate Cloudflare account and connecting it to the SASP server. In SASP I could point the nameservers to Cloudflare, and on Cloudflare's site I could point the traffic to SASP's IP address for my server, and thus it worked. Now, instead of limited SSL from SASP, I get the full suite of free options from Cloudflare's SSL.

If anyone else ever runs into this issue with them, I'd recommend this process, as they don't seem to mind, and I've had my websites live for 7 months without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

A rule that may do what you ask (untested) :

```
    <rule name="Redirect example.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: "Secure Connection Failed: The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" message from Firefox, like usual :/

Comment: I think the fault is with SmarterASP (perhaps wanting their $200). Try to complain to their Support, if they will cooperate.

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. Thanks for trying, I appreciate it.